# How to check if PDF files are online?

Tags: bash

I would like to iterate through a number of PDFs starting from [18001.pdf](http://dip21.bundestag.de/dip21/btp/18/18001.pdf) to N.pdf (adding 1 to the basename) and stop the loop as soon as a file is not online available. Below is the code that I guess is closest to what a solution might look like but actually there are multiple things not properly working it seems. The command in the while condition causes a syntax error f.x.

```
#!/bin/bash

path=http://dip21.bundestag.de/dip21/btp/18/
n=18001

while [ wget -q --spider $path$n.pdf ]
do
  n=$(($n+1))
done

echo $n
```

HST - my question is not about debugging this specific code - it mostly serves the purpose of illustrating what I would like to do. Then again, I would appreciate a solution using a loop and wget.

Comment: Why do you have a command line inside `[ ... ]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test the success of a command, don't put it inside `[` -- that's used to test the value of a conditional expression.

```
while wget -q --spider $path$n.pdf
do
    ...
done
```

Comment: nice! I thought you had to use those brackets. sometimes those seem to be needed when writing conditional statements.

Comment: BTW - is there a better (shorter, niftier) way to get this done?

Comment: It seems pretty reasonable to me.

Comment: If they have an index file, you may be able to use a recursive wget to download that and all the files it links to.